# Reveal bundle contents in Mountain Lion using ObjC

Tags: objective-c, bundle, nsworkspace

How can I reveal a bundle contents in Mountain Lion using `[NSWorkspace selectFile:nil inFileViewerRootedAtPath:pathEndingWithDotBundle]`? I mean: `pathEndingWithDotBundle` is a path whose basename is something like "folder.bundle". If I call this method this way, the Terminal opens up and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It opens Terminal because it thinks you want to launch the bundle, and that's the default application. I would open a bugreport against this, because the documentation does not say that it will open the path. It says it that it will display it in a file viewer. It would be reasonable for this to be an error (since a bundle is not *logically* a directory; it's just *phyiscally* a directory). But it makes no sense for it to do something random like try to launch another program.

That said, it's fairly easy to work around. Just select the `Contents` folder, which is required to be within the bundle:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:[pathEndingWithDotBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"] 
                 inFileViewerRootedAtPath:pathEndingWithDotBundle];
```

In 10.6+, you can use `activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:`

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[pathEndingWithDotBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"]];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:@[URL]];
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much. Is the "Contents" folder always required even if the bundle extension is not ".bundle"?

Comment: It is required if it is to be treated as a bundle by the OS. See Code Loading Programming Topics (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/AboutLoadableBundles.html) for the required layout.